# reverse proxy docker container to another two docker containers, how to have multiple instances on a single computer

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

In this project I have an apache docker container (called loadbalancer) which points to either of two apache docker containers. If the path is "/support*" then it goes to the support container otherwise it goes to webapp. Currently to achieve this I have hard coded my docker compose networks subnet and each containers ipv4 address. Then an apache conf file just points to those hard coded ips. This works great for local development environments.

However, it doesn't work for staging servers which need to host multiple instances of the project. I can't spin up more than one instance of this docker-compose network due to the hardcoded subnet/ipv4 addresses. How can I achieve this load balancer setup without hard coding the subnet so I can have multiple instances. Or is there a better solution to achieve the desired effect of many copies being hosted on a single server such as many vhosts in apache container. What would you suggest? As I have no clue as to what would be best practice here.

**loadbalancer.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    TimeOut -1

    ProxyPass "/support" "http://172.20.0.5/support"
    ProxyPassReverse "/support" "http://172.20.0.5/support"
    ProxyPass "/" "http://172.20.0.2/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://172.20.0.2/"

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    TimeOut -1
</VirtualHost>
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  pi-net:
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24

services:
    cli:
        container_name: cli
        build: ./docker/cli
        networks:
          pi-net:
            ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3
        volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: .
          target: /srv/www
        - type: bind
          source: $HOME/.gitconfig
          target: /home/developer/.gitconfig
        extra_hosts:
        - "pi.docker:172.20.0.2"
        user: developer
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        environment:
          GIT_PAGER: cat

    webapp:
        container_name: webapp
        build:
          context: ./docker/web-server
          args:
            - vhostsFileName=webapp.conf
        networks:
          pi-net:
            ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2
        ports:
        - 80
        volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: .
          target: /srv/www
        # depends on cli because cli entrypoint.sh is creating var/ files needed by httpd
        depends_on:
          - "cli"

    support:
        container_name: support
        build:
          context: ./docker/web-server
          args:
            - vhostsFileName=support.conf
        networks:
          pi-net:
            ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
        ports:
          - 80
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: .
            target: /srv/www
        # depends on cli because cli entrypoint.sh is creating var/ files needed by httpd
        depends_on:
          - "cli"

    loadbalancer:
        container_name: loadbalancer
        build:
          context: ./docker/web-server
          args:
            - vhostsFileName=loadbalancer.conf
        networks:
          pi-net:
            ipv4_address: 172.20.0.6
        ports:
          - 80:80

    db:
        container_name: db
        build: ./docker/mysql
        networks:
          pi-net:
            ipv4_address: 172.20.0.4
        ports:
        - 3306:3306
        volumes:
        - db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: pi
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
        restart: always

volumes:
    db:
        driver: local
```

Comment: how about some args? https://forums.docker.com/t/environment-variables-in-args/27522

Comment: That's for regular docker containers, I'm not sure you can get args to modify a yml file itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker provides [an internal DNS service](https://docs.docker.com/network/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) to resolve container names as host names, and Docker Compose [provides a network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  You should make two changes:

1. In your Apache configuration, replace the explicit IP addresses with the name of the corresponding service block in the `docker-compose.yml`: `http://support/support`, for example.
2. Delete all of the `networks:` and `container_name:` settings in the `docker-compose.yml`, since they're redundant and limit reuse of the file.  (Docker will assign IP addresses for you and Docker Compose will pick container names, but there's nothing wrong with these defaults.)

(Many questions of this form also use the outdated `links:` functionality; it's safe to delete all of the `links:` blocks too.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some testing with this later. Not sure why I didn't think of this sooner considering I do that with my database connection details

Comment: Answers my original question so I'll mark it as accepted, however due to my use of extra_hosts: it hasn't worked out since I havent been able to successfully change that ip usage to "loadbalancer"

Comment: Changed out extra_hosts for external_links and it works just as well for some reason. Hope this helps someone